# when i add bg and border to footer it combines with the upper content, how do i solve it?

Tags: html, css

```
 .inner {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
            padding: 12px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .outer::after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }
        #footer {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgb(213, 209, 209);
            padding: 12px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="outer">
        <div class="inner left">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, rem temporibus a animi libero nihil, aliquam eaque vero nisi voluptas quis eligendi! Temporibus quam sit eligendi numquam quas facilis perspiciatis?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo delectus quibusdam exercitationem placeat, quasi dolore laborum animi officiis, consectetur alias, ex mollitia unde reprehenderit. Ratione sed dolorem asperiores fugiat voluptate!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
    </div>
```

The footer properties are attached to upper content, i did not add any attribute to the upper div.

I want footer and upper content to be separate contents and work with different attributes.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Probably due to the fact, that you are floating .main, and all its children - and the "clearfix" code in your CSS is explicitly commented out ... You should really rather go look into flexbox and/or grid, instead of still using float for such basic layout stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the issue however exactly I did experience it. to fix it I did the following:

```css
footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  /* ^ this is the important part to fix it */
  margin-top: 2%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  /* ^ this too */
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <footer>
    lorem ipsum de lore set amet
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

my only concern with this is i think it creates a secondary problem of a small margin on the left side, that may just be an issue with my code though.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use float and width for layouts, use flexbox instead. Flexbox is very simple and perfect. Flexbox automatically scales the element, means you don't event have to set the width of the elements.

Here's your code by using flexbox and modified a bit.

```css
.main-cont {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 10px 0px; 
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
}

div.left, div.middle, div.right {
    border-radius: 5px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: 10px 0px; 
    padding: 4px; 
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.footer { 
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: rgb(230, 227,224);
    padding: 10px; 
    margin-top: 10px; 
    text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="main-cont">
    <div class="left">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur </div>
    <div class="middle">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectet</div>
    <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <h2>Bye</h2>
</div>
```

Isn't it working perfectly just like you expected.

Also, remember that, you shouldn't provide images or links to images of your code. You should provide the code instead if you want it answered.

Comment: i just don't understand why some div is using the properties of other  div even when i dont mention it.

Comment: IMO, It is happening maybe because the div with classes left, right and center are going in the footer div, because of some side-effect of float and widths.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source you sent it is working correctly. However without loading the style.css and normalize.css.It usually overlaps some CSS rule when there are many imports and at this point it sees the question of the order in which it is called (first instructions with !important, then the CSS line, then inside the style block, order of the imported files). Start by inspecting the elements with F12 in your browser to see if there is any padding or margin in the header or at the beginning of the section with id home.

Another tip, use semantics. Elements like header, main and footer.

```
<body>
    <!-- header design -->
    <header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Testing</a>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- home section design -->
    <main>
        <section class="home" id="home">
            <div class="home-content">
                <h1>Testing</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos corporis nam error officiis atque beatae molestias voluptatibus debitis.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <a href="#" class="logo">Testing</a>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </footer>
</body>
```

So you can write the rule directly for the element.

```
<style>
header nav a { color: #00c617; }
footer nav a { color: #00a6de; }
</style>
```